# Append date to custom post type url slug

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, slug

I have a sports website that will have very similar slugs:

```
http://example.com/match/teamA-vs-teamB
```

Sooner than later, teams A and B will play again, and the slugs will repeat themselves:

```
http://example.com/match/teamA-vs-teamB-1
```

The solution I found was to prepend a date to the match, making it look like this:

```
http://example.com/match/2017-01-31/teamA-vs-teamB
```

This will guarantee I have unique slugs and is also user friendly.

I tried to change "rewrite" option on `register_post_type` without success, because whatever I add there will be the same for all "match" post types.

How can I append the scheduled post date to the slug?

Comment: How about creating a custom post type with a taxonomy? Where the CP is match and its tax. is teamA vs teamB

Comment: There's a lot of related questions around this. I think this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23702560/450127 (or a modification of it) will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [Custom Post Type Permalinks plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/)

Works pretty well:

[image: Append date to custom post type wordpress]